# Captilizing particular words in PHP string

Tags: php

I would like to take a string and seek out specific words and capitalize them. So for a string  like "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.", I want to be able to only captalize ipsum and adipisicing. So basically put a capitalization filter on certain words.

How can this be done?

Comment: regex will help . see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: `str_replace` would work...

Answer (score 4):

Don't use regex for this, `str_replace` is the clearest, easiest way:

```
$str = str_replace(
    array('ipsum','adipisicing'), 
    array('Ipsum','Adipisicing'), 
    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.'
);
```

Or a bit more clever:

```
$words = array('ipsum', 'adipisicing');
$str = str_replace($words, array_map('ucfirst', $words), 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$capitalize_me = array('word1','word2'....'wordn');
$capitalized  = array_map('ucfirst',$capitalize_me);
$new_sentence = str_replace($capitalize_me,$capitalized,$old_sentence);
```

not the most efficient, but does the work

Answer (score 0):

There are too many ways to do this...

- [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)
- [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)
- [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) string into an array and iterate through with `str_replace`, then [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) array back into a string

Answer (score 0):

This works well for me:

```
<?php 

$word_array = array('ipsum', 'adipisicing');
$soucre_sentence = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.';

$captilize_words = array();
$replacements_captalized = array();
$replacements_all_caps = array();

foreach ($word_array as $word) {
  $captilize_words[] = '/\b' . $word . '\b/i';
  $replacements_captalized[] = ucfirst(strtolower($word));
  $replacements_all_caps[] = strtoupper($word);
}

$ret = preg_replace($captilize_words, $replacements_all_caps, $soucre_sentence);

echo $ret;

?>
```

Added capitalized and ALL CAPS replacements since I am not clear on what you really want your output to be. Choose one!

**EDIT:** Genuinely did not know about the flexibility of `array_map` (that @mmattax) and reworked it one last time with that tip.

```
<?php 

$word_array = array('ipsum', 'adipisicing');
$soucre_sentence = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.';

$captilize_words = array_map(function ($word) { return '/\b' . $word . '\b/i'; }, $word_array);
$replacements_captalized = array_map('ucfirst', $word_array);
$replacements_all_caps = array_map('strtoupper', $word_array);

$ret = preg_replace($captilize_words, $replacements_all_caps, $soucre_sentence);

echo $ret;

?>
```

Comment: That's a bit overkill, can be done in one line: str_replace($captilize_words, array_map('ucfirst', $captilize_words), 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.');

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.';
$caps = 'ipsum|adipisicing';
echo preg_replace_callback(
    '/(^|\s)('.$caps.')(\s|$)/'
  , function($m){ return $m[1].ucfirst($m[2]).$m[3]; }
  , $str
);
```

That regexp could probably be better (I'm thinking you could use \W), but if you don't account for whitespace before/after the word, it will replace in the middle of words too.